# mod_rewrite 404 Error

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, configuration, http-status-code-404

I've been looking at the posts and some Google Groups stuffs for fixing mod_rewrite for use with CakePHP (as well as the CakePHP docs), but I can't seem to get mod_rewrite to work correctly.

CakePHP installs fine and I get the main page, I get: [image]
Then I created a Model app/Model/Format.php:

```
<?php

    /**
     * File: app/Model/Format.php
     *
     * Format Model
     */
    class Format extends AppModel
    {
        var $name = 'Format';

        // <hasMany>
        var $hasMany = array(
                                'DVD' => array('className' => 'DVD')
                            );
    }

    ?>
```

a Controller app/Controller/FormatsController.php with a method:

```
function index()
    {           // Ignore Format -related- data
        $this->Format->recursive = 0;

        // Get all formats from the database that have a status of '1'
        $formats = $this->Format->find('all', array(
                                                        'conditions' => array('Format.status' => '1')
                                                    ));

        // Save the Formats in a variable for display from the View
        $this->set('formats', $formats);
    }
```

and finally a View app/View/Formats/index.ctp:

```
<?php
    // File: app/Views/Formats/index.ctp
?>

<div class='formats index'>

    <table>
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th> Format Name</th>
                <th> Description </th>
                <th> Actions </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php

            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

My .htaccess files in the cakephp root dir, app root dir, webroot dir all match the CakePHP suggestions @ http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html .

I also added RewriteBase [path to my app dir] to each of those .htaccess files since someone in a Google group said it worked for them.

However, whenever I try and load "cakecms/Formats/index", I get:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing?
I'm on a new laptop today, and this *was* all working on my last one. I have to be missing something...

Comment: Did you set `AllowOverride All` as described in http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess ?

Comment: Yeah.
My default directory is setup like this:

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Options +MultiViews
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
</Directory>

Also, 'apachectl configtest' returns "Syntax OK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I *finally* figured out what it was that I was missing.
I never changed the default

```
<Directory [DocumentRoot] />
....
</Directory>
```

directory in my httpd.conf file.

While I was allowing Overrides in my more specific `<Directory...>` listings, I was denying them in my default DocumentRoot one.
Once I changed to `AllowOverride All` in the default DocRoot Directory in httpd.conf, the Cake/Apache URL routing works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a url rewriting issue you generally get an error message on the default homepage which you don't so that's probably not the issue. The url you should be checking is `cakecms/formats` (note lowercase "f"). The "index" part is optional for index action.

Comment: Also make sure you have debug turned on in your app/Config/core.php

Comment: cakecms/formats returns the same page and the same error as the screenshot above.
My current debug level is set to 2 but I still just get "Not Found".

I've never used the DebugKit for CakePHP; I think I'll install it and see if it offers any new insights.